# How to backup statistics in sql?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Let's just say I have a table A with some data on it in SSMS. There are sub tables such as columns, constraints,triggers,indexes and statistics etc.

I want to create a similar table with same properties as table A. I know I need to go to Script Table As-> Create To-> New Query Window to duplicate the table structure.

However, after doing that, I realized the statistics in my new table is empty when there are statistics in table A. Did I miss out something?

Comment: *Did I miss out something?* SSMS has a "Script Statistics" option but I mean unless you're putting data in the table at the same time ... copying the stats seems a bit pointless https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/30/sql-server-how-to-script-statistics-from-ssms-scripting-statistics-is-disabled-in-ssms/

Comment: Yes I am aware of the option and I marked it as true. However, after inserting certain data into the new table, the stats still seem empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can script the statistics blob only with the following bit of powershell (which I yoinked from an old blog post of mine):

```
pushd;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
popd;

$opts = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ScriptingOptions;
$opts.OptimizerData = $true;

$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server ".";
$database = $server.Databases["AdventureWorks2008R2"];

foreach ($table in $database.Tables) {
    foreach ($stat in $table.Statistics) {
        $stat.Script($opts);
    }
}
```

The above will script out all statistics (including the histogram data) for all tables in the AdventureWorks2008R2 database. You should be able to tailor it to your needs.